# Evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,-1)}\frac{xy+1}{x^2-y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,-1)}\frac{xy+1}{x^2-y^2}$$

I was going to try polar coordinates but I don't know if I should input $-1$ or $1$ into $r$. I also tried L'Hopital's rule but don't know whether I should get the derivative with respect to $x$ or $y$.

Comment: You could start by letting $x=1+h$ and $y=-1+k$. What does $(h,k)$ tend to then?

Answer (score 2):

$y=-1:$

$\dfrac{1-x}{(x-1)(x+1)}= -\dfrac{1}{x+1}.$

$\lim_{ x \rightarrow 1} -\dfrac{1}{x+1}=-1/2$.

$x=1:$

$\dfrac{y+1}{1-y^2}= \dfrac{y+1}{(1-y)(1+y)}= \dfrac{1}{1-y}.$

$\lim_{y \rightarrow -1} \dfrac{1}{1-y}=1/2$.

The limit does not exist .

Comment: $\frac{xy+1}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{xy+1}{2y}(\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{1}{x-y})=\frac{xy+1}{2xy+2y^2}-\frac{xy+1}{2xy-2y^2}$

$\lim_{(x, y)→(1, -1)}\frac{xy+1}{2xy-2y^2}=\frac{0}{-2-2}=0$

for other fraction using L'Hopital rule we take partial derivative and we have:

$\lim_{(x, y)→(1, -1)}\frac{xy+1}{2xy+2y^2}=\lim_{(x, y)→(1, -1)}\frac{1+\frac{1}{y}}{2x+2y}=\lim_{(x, y)→(1, -1)}\frac{1-1/y^2}{2+2}=0$

Comment: Sirious.I am a bit at a loss following your comment.Your last line and the line before don't match. In the limit 1+1/y goes to 0, and so does 2x+2y ,undetermined, while you get 0 in your last line.Your thoughts?

Comment: The limit of lat line is $\frac{-1}{4}$, I had error. So the limit of initial fraction i s $\frac {-1}{4}.$